# ExcuteNonQuery returns null when inserting data to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-insert, executenonquery

I have a web page which displays user posts and allows a user to add a new post. I have used an `SqlDataSource` to bring the data from DB, and I have bound a repeater to it in order to display the retrieved posts. My problem is when the user wants to insert a new post. Here is the logic that I'm following:

1- Getting the data entered by the user in the post area, like text and images (the user can upload images in the post).

2- Building the insert query with the values obtained from the new post area.

3- Executing the query.

4- Updating the `SqlDataSource` using `DataBind()`.

5- Updating the repeater associated with the data source using `DataBind()`.

For some reason the insert command inserts doesn't work. I have tried insersion using typical SqlConnection method, SqlConnection method with parameter query (where I use parameters instead of using the inserted post info directly, eg @text), and I have even tried to perform the insertion using the datasource itself, nothing worked. Here is my code:

```
protected void submitPost(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uploadImageBtn.HasFile)  //check if a file was uploaded by the user. 
    {
        //step 1: save at the server: 
            uploadImageBtn.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedImages/")  + uploadImageBtn.FileName); //working :)
            String fileName = uploadImageBtn.FileName;  //get the uploaded file name to store it in the database. 
        //get current date and time to insert them in DB:
            DateTime dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime (DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyy"));
            DateTime timeValue = Convert.ToDateTime ( DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));


         string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
         con.Open(); //open db

         string query2 = "insert into posts_tbl (postDate, postTime, postText, postVideo2, PostImage2, pUserName, boundPost) VALUES (@date,@time,@post,@video,@img,@userName,@boundPost)";

         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, con); //build a command 
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateValue);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", timeValue);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", post_txt.Text);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@video", "NULL");
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", fileName);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", "name");
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boundPost", "NULL");

        int returned= command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //returns null

        con.Close();
        postsSource.DataBind();
        postsRepeater.DataBind(); 

    }//end if
}//end method
```

Here is the code I wrote using the data source itself:

```
postsSource.InsertCommandType= SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
postsSource.InsertCommand = "insert into posts_tbl (postDate, postTime, postText, postVideo2, PostImage2, pUserName, boundPost) VALUES (@date,@time,@post,@video,@img,@userName,@boundPost)";
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("date", dateValue);
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("time", timeValue);
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("post", post_txt.Text.ToString());
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("video", "Null");
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("img", fileName);
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("userName", "name");
postsSource.InsertParameters.Add("boundPost", "NULL");
postsSource.Insert();

postsSource.DataBind();
postsRepeater.DataBind();
```

The last method however, doesn't allow assigning non-string value to the parameters (like in dateValue and timeValue which must be Datetime).

Can anyone please tell me what is causing the insertion error? And, whether I'm updating the data source and the repeater correctly or not?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column _boundPost_? (and _postVideo2_)

Comment: Are you sure about `null` being returned? `ExecuteNonQuery` actually returns integer, so it cannot return null

Comment: @Steve, these fields contain string values and are of types char.

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger and follow your code step by step. As @Andrei says the ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer. There is no way that method returns null. Are you sure to not have some empty error catching block that hides the real error message?

Comment: @Andrei, I after checking I found that the error is related to some null value, I was wrong, it doesn't return null. I will recheck my code.

Comment: @Steve, it doesn't return null, I will check my code again and try to find the error.

Comment: Does the code actually throw an exception? That alone may contain all info you need

Comment: @Andrei, thanks a lot, I figured out the problem, I was inserting a null value for a field that requires int. Now the code is working, thank you.

Comment: @Steve, you were right, I have mistakenly inserted null into boundPost which requires int, now the problem is solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dania, if you did figure this one out, please feel free to post self-answer and accept it, to help future readers of this thread. If you do not find this significant enough, perhaps consider just removing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing the code with **Steve** and  **Andrei** , I figured out my problem.

I was inserting a null value into a field that requires int data type. I just removed that field from the insert query, and everything worked fine.

Thanks All.